# Is there a way that I can override a file within the JRE on execution? That is, without editing the JRE?

Tags: java, jar

I want to add a numberpad to JavaFX's virtual keyboard.

I've tried several other solutions (including using a keyboard from GitHub or trying JavaFX's numeric virtual keyboard), but this would be the easiest and most practical.

I found the text file (com.sun.scene.control.skin.TextBoard.txt) that is read by com.sun.scene.control.skin.FXVKSkin.class to create the normal keyboard. I added the numpad, and it works fine. However, I want to do this without actually editing the JRE.

This is the relevant part of FXVKSkin.java that loads the keyboard.

```java
private List<List<Key>> loadBoard(String type) {
    List<List<Key>> tmpBoard = boardMap.get(type);
    if (tmpBoard != null) {
        return tmpBoard;
    }
     String boardFileName = type.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + type.substring(1).toLowerCase() + "Board.txt";
    try {
        tmpBoard = new ArrayList<List<Key>>(5);
        List<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>(20);
         InputStream boardFile = FXVKSkin.class.getResourceAsStream(boardFileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(boardFile));
```

Alternatively, would I be able to just keep TextBoard.txt in my project's classpath and somehow point to that copy instead of the one within the JRE when FXVKSkin.java says "FXVKSkin.class.getResourceAsStream("TextBoard.txt")?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

I took jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, which is the jar file in which com.sun.scene.control.skin.TextBoard.txt resides, and copied it into my project's working directory. I deleted everything within the copy except for the path com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextBoard.txt, and added "-Xbootclasspath/a:jfxrt.jar" as a boot option. I am still on Java 8, so this might not work for later versions, but it's working for me.

Comment: For Java 9 and later, the solution is to use `--patch-module` with the `javac` and `java` commands.

Comment: @StephenC Awesome, thanks! I saw that somewhere which is why I noted that it might not work in later versions of Java, but I didn't test --patch-module on later versions so I didn't want to say definitively if that was the solution for later versions. I'll take note of that in case we update. Thanks!